# Web Service teste dos Correios - erro SSL

Tags: c#, .net, web-service

Alguém já teve esse problema ao referenciar a [web service](https://apphom.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl) para testes e implementações dos correios.

Preciso efetuar algumas validações mas não consigo executar nenhum método sem que ocorra erros de ssl.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dois métodos abaixo servem para aceitar qualquer certificado que os web services estejam utilizando

```
    private static void SetCertificatePolicy()
    {
        // Código necessário para acessar serviços remotos
        // Evita o erro HTTP 417
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += RemoteCertificateValidate;
    }

    private static bool RemoteCertificateValidate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors error)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Como eu poderia aplicar isso dentro do meu contexto ? Mesmo com esse erro, consigo importar todas as classes e métodos da web service. Só que quando tento executar um método especifico da um erro de ssl.

Comment: Tente chamar o SetCertificatePolicy() antes de instanciar a sua classe do webservice e efetuar as chamadas.. e me avise se der certo!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente !!!!!! Estou muito feliz. Muito obrigado !!!!! Consegue me explicar resumidamente (não precisa se não quiser) como isso funciona ? Conceitos mesmo.

Comment: Fala amigo, fico muito feliz de ter dado certo, aconselho você a criar uma classe de útils para guardar esse cara pois no decorrer da sua integração com o webservice podem surgir outros métodos. No código acima basicamente eu seto um callback  na validação do certificado, e o mesmo sempre retorna True, retornando sempre como se seu certificado fosse válido :)

Comment: Valeu (-; ......

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no certificado do webservice. Provavelmente o certificado é auto-assinado, o que faz com que ele seja marcado como 'falso' pelos navegadores/aplicações.

Não há muito o que fazer. Você pode tentar forçar sua aplicação/servidor a aceitar o certificado falso, porém não é garantido que funcione.